# Laravel form request check if two passwords match?

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on a user registration form in laravel 5. I wish to know is it possible to use laravel's form request validation to check if the two passwords submitted by the user are thesame. Is it possible to do that with using requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

There is an validator called `confirmed`.

> **confirmed**
>
> The field under validation must have a matching field of
>   `foo_confirmation`. For example, if the field under validation is
>   `password`, a matching `password_confirmation` field must be present in
>   the input.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed